# How to correctly measure the duty from an interrupt that is used for counting

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, pwm

Trying to get the duty cycle % from an input (pin27) on my ESP32 that is currently used for analog input to read out the voltage provided by a GM driver.

Anybody has an idea on how could I achieve this?

- Used controller: https://heltec.org/project/wifi-kit-32/
- Used HV driver: https://rhelectronics.net/store/high-voltage-400v-geiger-tube-driver-two-channels-with-signal-buffer-for-muon-cosmic-ray-coincidence-detector.html

Thanks!

Comment: You could enable the external interrupt for that pin, triggering on rising and falling edge. Keep tabs on what's in the timer's register on each interrupt and you can calculate the frequency and duty cycle.